# asp.net passing parameter to js function in listview

Tags: asp.net

I want to pass parameter to my js function in my listview. I did that with one parameter. Like that :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnRezAktar" runat="server" Text="Aktar" OnClientClick='<%# "SubmitPage(" + Eval("o_no") +" );"%>' />

 <script language="javascript">
        function SubmitPage(o_no) {
            window.opener.document.getElementById('txtRoomNo').value = o_no.toString();
            this.close();
        }
    </script>
```

but I want to pass two parameter, it does not work:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRezAktar" runat="server" Text="Aktar" OnClientClick='<%# "SubmitPage(" + Eval("o_no") + "," + Eval("k_ad") + " );"%>' />

 <script language="javascript">
        function SubmitPage(o_no, k_ad) {
            window.opener.document.getElementById('txtRoomNo').value = o_no.toString();
             window.opener.document.getElementById('txtNameSurname').value = k_ad.toString();
       this.close();
        }
    </script>
```

What is wrong with that?

Comment: Try to put a double quote or single quote around the second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OnClientClick='<%# Eval("o_no", "SubmitPage(\"{0}\", ") + Eval("k_ad", "\"{0}\")") %>'
```